# Beautiful soup doesn't see part of the html file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a trouble to get max_value from input element of HTML.

```
link = 'http://www.bcra.gob.ar//PublicacionesEstadisticas/Principales_variables_datos_i.asp?serie=7935&detalle=Monetary Policy Rate (APR %)'
html_data = requests.get(link).text
soup_direct_link = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'lxml')
max_start_date = soup_direct_link.find('form', class_ = 'form-inline').input['max']
```

I tried some other ways that could find in the Internet but nothing helped.
Also, there are very familiar page, that is  below, works successfully:

'*http://www.bcra.gob.ar//PublicacionesEstadisticas/Principales_variables_datos_i.asp?serie=246&detalle=BCRA International Reserves (in million dollars - provisional figures subject to valuation change*'

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Comment: What are you trying to extract from the page?

Comment: The data that pops up after choosing the min and max dates ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the page source you will see that class is not present. Instead, you can use an attribute selector as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://www.bcra.gob.ar//PublicacionesEstadisticas/Principales_variables_datos_i.asp?serie=246&detalle=BCRA', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('[max]')['max'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Webdriver from Selenium to first get the "full" source code. It seems like the requests object does not have the fully rendered html code. This may be due to certain scripts that are not "loaded" with the requests approach:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

link = 'http://www.bcra.gob.ar//PublicacionesEstadisticas/Principales_variables_datos_i.asp?serie=7935&detalle=Monetary Policy Rate (APR %)'

#Download the chrome drivers and provide their location instead of "XYZ"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\XYZ\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(link)

#Now you can access the code rendered by the Chrome webdriver: 
soup_direct_link = BeautifulSoup(str(driver.page_source), 'lxml')

max_start_date = soup_direct_link.find('form', class_ = 'form-inline').input["max"]
print(max_start_date)
```